# Is it called co-related query or correlated query?

Tags: sql, terminology

I see terms co-related and correlated queries used interchangeably. co-related = to correlate.

what is the correct term, or are they both correct?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little Googling can give a good indication of which terms are in general usage**:

- "co-related subquery" = About 303
  results
- "correlated subquery" = About 21,600
  results

Clearly, "correlated subquery" wins hands down.

However, when `subquery` is shortened to `query` the result is not so clear cut:

- "co-related queries" = About 5,290
  results
- "correlated queries" = About 9,000
  results

My personal take is that "co-related queries" and "correlated queries" are newbie, sloppy or otherwise informal usage of "correlated subquery".

** Knowing the correct term may not be useful (unless you want to be a smart arse like me ;) e.g.

- SQL "correlation name" = About 24,400
  results
- SQL "as clause" = About 17,400 result
- SQL alias = About 2,670,000 results

Conclusion: hardly anyone uses the terms from the SQL Standards, most people prefer (perhaps in ignorance) the vernacular.

I don't think you can say using 'alias' is "incorrect". Using the technically correct term may not get you understood if you fail to also use the vernacular!

Answer (score 2):

The term used is 'correlated sub-queries', where the hyphenation (or absence of hyphenation) in 'sub-queries' is debatable but 'correlated' is not.